# is there a way to get the list of id from result of pagination() in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, pagination, eloquent

To do pagination in laravel, the easiest way is by:

```
$items = ModelOfItem::orderBy('my_order_field', 'asc')->paginate(10);
```

However, in this pagination, I need to relate data from another table to this page. Currently, I do it by:

```
$item_ids = ModelOfItem::orderBy('my_order_field', 'asc')->take(10)->list('id');
$related_items = ModelOfRelatedItem::whereIn($item_ids)->get();
```

However, it needs to query database twice on data that I already have in hand, and it is painful to handle page after first page. Is there a way I can get a list of id from the pagination result so I can use to directly query on the second table?

P.S. It is an old project so it is still using Laravel 4.2.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use joins? You can join the tables & call `->paginate(10)` as the end method. if you still want this approach for whatsoever reason.. You can call `->lists('id')` on paginator object as well.. like this:

```
$items = ModelOfItem::orderBy('my_order_field', 'asc')->paginate(10);
$item_ids = $items->lists('id');
$related_items = ModelOfRelatedItem::whereIn($item_ids)->get();
```

Comment: Because one item needs to join with multiple related items. Joining table will results in duplicated rows. Related items will be display as a pop-up when clicking the item in the table, and I don't want to do ajax.

Comment: If you don't want to use joins, you can stick to your approach with pagination as well.. I've just updated my answer.. try this.

Comment: @cytsunny works well for me.. what error do you get?

Comment: It says the method is not found. Are you using laravel 4.2?

Comment: No, I'm on 5.2 and working fine for me.. I've one project on 4.2 as well.. will check and update you by evening.

Comment: I just tried same code on one of my project with Laravel 4.2 and it works perfectly fine. Can you please share the exact code you're using.

Comment: The error message is :
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::lists()

Comment: The exact code cannot be shared as it is not owned by me, but basically the same as what I shared, with the name changed. Not sure if it matters, but I am running PHP 5.5.15